# Android RecyclerView.OnScrollListener with dynamic loading not updating UI/ weird behavior?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dynamic-loading

In my `RecyclerView`, I am implementing dynamic loading and need to load item when a user has scrolled to the bottom.

Code for dynamic loading:

```
     mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

           // if lastVisibleItem is the last item in my list add more!
           if (mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == mlist.size() - 1){
              mlist.add(randomItem);
              mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mlist.size() - 1);
           }
        }
    });
```

I start with an empty list. I am testing by first manually adding an item to trigger the `onScrolled` callback and everything works perfectly. My first added item triggers the first call to `OnScrolled`, updates the UI, and now I have two items in my list.

The first call to `onScrolled` should chain a second call to `onScrolled`. The second should chain a third call and so forth. This because of the method behavior as described below (**notice the bold**):

> onScrolled: Callback method to be invoked when the RecyclerView has been scrolled. This will be called after the scroll has completed. **This callback will also be called if visible item range changes after a layout calculation.**

On the second call is where things get weird. The third item DOES get added to my list, so I know it gets triggered, however my UI does NOT update. Things get even more weird. The third item will suddenly show up in my UI when I **CLICK** the `RecyclerView` with my mouse. Why is that??

Once my third item loads (by me clicking the `RecyclerView`) it will trigger another call to `onScrolled` to display my fourth item. The same weird behavior will continue for the rest of the items.

Am I misunderstanding something here? What can cause this behavior? How should I fix this? TY!!

Comment: try adding super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

Comment: did addind super  work ?

Comment: Ty, but nope didn't work. I don't think the super method does anything. It has no code in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Have you tried that inside of your onScrollListener?